# How can I successfully extract this substring in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Here is the offending code. I haven't done much string manipulation yet, and am currently having issues.

```
if (orderid != orderlist[orderlist.Count - 1])
    {
    response2 = GetSubstringByString("{\"orderid\": \"" + orderid + "\"", "{\"orderid\": \"", response2);
    }
    else
    {
    response2 = GetSubstringByString("{\"orderid\": \"" + orderid + "\"", "success", response2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Response 2 is: " + response2);
    logger.Log("Writing " + writepath + filename);
    File.WriteAllText(writepath + filename, response2);
    }


public string GetSubstringByString(string a, string b, string c) //trims beginning and ending of string
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String a is: " + a + "String b is: " + b + "String c is: " + c);
            return c.Substring((c.IndexOf(a) + a.Length), (c.IndexOf(b) - c.IndexOf(a) - a.Length));
        }
```

I am having issues extracting a substring, as the beginning and ending strings are the same, and therefore it is unable to differentiate the strings from each other.

Here is the main issue:

```
response2 = GetSubstringByString("{\"orderid\": \"" + orderid + "\"", "{\"orderid\": \"", response2);
```

Is there a way I can add a check if the orderid for the ending string differs from the starting string orderid? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like you have JSON data there.  You should just use a JSON parser rather than trying to parse it yourself.

Comment: This is JSON. Don't extract it via substring manipulation, deserialize it using a JSON library.

Comment: FYI there is an overload of `string.IndexOf` that takes the index to start searching from, but as already mentioned you should use the appropriate parser for your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working with code that was already set to scan rather than parse JSON in the optimal fashion.

I utilized this regex to remove orderid before each number as to not cause scanner length exceptions. I also overloaded string.IndexOf as mentioned by juharr.

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("orderid")); //replace first occurrence of orderid
response2 = regex.Replace(response2, "", parsecount-1);

public string GetSubstringByString(string a, string b, string c) //trims beginning and ending of string
        {
            logger.Log("String a is: " + a + "String b is: " + b + "String c is: " + c);
            var offset = c.IndexOf(b);

            //lastcheck will return 0 if it's last element in orderlist, because ending string differs for last
            return c.Substring((c.IndexOf(a) + a.Length), (c.IndexOf(b, offset + lastcheck) - c.IndexOf(a) - a.Length));
        }
```